# JK Flip Flop Debugging Iteration Limit error in VHDL Modelsim

Tags: vhdl

I'm writing vhdl code for a jk-flip-flop on modelsim and i get an error when i try to simulate it: Error: Iteration limit reached at time 0 ns.

I'm not sure what it means, but I've looked through much of my source code for errors to no success. Can anyone guess what the problem might be?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;


entity SRlatch is
port(S,R:in bit; Q : inout bit ; QN : inout bit := '1');
end SRlatch;

architecture structural of SRlatch is
begin
Q <=  S nand QN;
QN <= R nand Q;
end;


entity JKFlipFlopStruct is
port(J,K,clk : in bit ; Q : inout bit ; QN : inout bit);
end JKFlipFlopStruct;

architecture structural of JKFlipFlopStruct is

  component SRlatch is
   port(S,R:in bit; Q : inout bit ; QN : inout bit := '1');
  end component;

  signal J0,K0,J1,K1,J2,K2 : bit;

begin

  J0 <= not ( J and QN and clk) );
  K0 <= not ( K and Q and clk) );

  f1 : SRlatch port map ( J0,K0,J1,K1 );

  J2 <= not ( J1 and (not clk) );
  K2 <= not ( K1 and (not clk) );
  f2 : SRlatch port map ( J2,K2,Q,QN );

end structural;
```

[JK Flop Flop negative edge triggered]

see image :https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3m1J.gif

Answer (score 1):

As Russell say, this error usually indicates that ModelSim is stuck in an infinite loop. In VHDL, this can happen when a signal is placed in the sensitivity list and this signal is changed in the process.

A simple example:

```
process (sig)
begin
  sig <= not sig;
end;
```

Your problem is also in this case. But there are some differences.

**1. For any concurrent signal assignment statement, there is an equivalent process statement with the same meaning.** (See [VHDL LRM 93 $9.5](http://www.dacya.ucm.es/dani/manual.pdf) for more details)

So, in your code,

```
J0 <= not ( J and QN and clk) );
```

is short hand notation for

```
process
begin
   J0 <= not ( J and QN and clk) );
   wait on J, QN, clk;
end process;
```

or

```
process (J, QN, clk)
begin
    J0 <= not ( J and QN and clk) );
end process;
```

Others concurrent statements are the same.

**2. About simulation cycle** (See VHDL LRM 93 $12.6.4 and [Delta Delays](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~ece327/protected/modelsim/htmldocs/modelsim_se_user/a_vhdl10.html))
In eacy cycle, the values of all signals in the description are computed. If as a result of this computation an event occurs on a given signal, process statements that are sentitive to that signal will resume and will be executed as part of the simulation cycle.

In your code:

```
f2 : SRlatch port map ( J2,K2,Q,QN );
```

it's equivalent process:

```
process (J2, K2)
begin
   Q <=  J2 nand QN;
   QN <= K2 nand Q; 
end process;
```

along with other processes make an infinite loop.
For example,

```
the J-K Flip-Flop is stable @ 100 ns + 0 delta time
J or K or clk changes       @ 100 ns + 0 delta time
J0 or K0          \ ---
J1 or K1              |__ cost several delta times
J2 or K2              |   Suppose that Q changes @ 100 ns + 3 delta time
Q or QN  changes  / ---     
Then the value of K0 will change again!!
This result in a infinite loop becase 100 ns + n delta time = 100 ns. Time never advanceds.
```

**Solutions:**
1.Make your design a sequential one (ie. use a synchronic clock).

```
process (clk)
begin
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
        -- signal assignment
    end if;
end process;
```

2.Use delay assignment. So, in the SRlatch.vhd, you should write

```
Q <=  S nand QN after 1 ns;
QN <= R nand Q after 2 ns;
```

Unsymmetrical delay is used to ensure that either `Q` or `QN` sets up first and then feedbacks to set the other one.

Also refer to a similar question: [Debugging Iteration Limit error in VHDL Modelsim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9269916/2778477).

Comment: And with the delay assignment if you remove the default preset to QN in the SRLatch port declaration and make the two delays in the assignments to Q and QN unsymmetrical the shortest delay path will end up getting set. Without the unsymmetrical delay in the assignments and no default preset Q and QN will switch back and forth constantly. This demonstrates metastability and one way to overcome it.  See [SR latch](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Digital_Circuits/Latches#SR_latch), third paragraph.

Comment: @DavidKoontz Thanks. I've modified it.

Answer (score 0):

Iteration limit means that you have created a feedback loop in your design and you made the simulator very angry!  It cannot resolve the loop.

Use a clocked process to set J0 and K0.

```
jk_flippy_floppy : process (clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
     J0 <= not ( J and QN );
     K0 <= not ( K and Q  );
  end if;
end process jk_flippy_floppy;
```

Comment: Try simulating JUST your SR Latch to see if you see that same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity SRlatch is
  port(S,R:in bit; Q : inout bit := '0' ; QN : inout bit := '1');
end SRlatch;

architecture structural of SRlatch is
begin
  Q <=  S nand QN;
  QN <= R nand Q;
end structural;

entity JKFlipFlopStruct is
  port(J,K,clk : in bit ; Q : inout bit ; QN : inout bit:= '1');
end JKFlipFlopStruct;

architecture structural of JKFlipFlopStruct is

  component SRlatch is
   port(S,R:in bit; Q : inout bit ; QN : inout bit := '1');
  end component;

  signal J1 : bit;
  signal J0,K0,K1,J2,K2 : bit:= '1';

begin

  J0 <= not ( J and QN and (not clk) );
  K0 <= not ( K and Q and (not clk) );

  f1 : SRlatch port map ( J0,K0,J1,K1 );

  J2 <= not ( J1 and clk );
  K2 <= not ( K1 and clk );

  f2 : SRlatch port map ( J2,K2,Q,QN );

end structural;
```

this is the correct code